# Align video with Image In html without Css

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align a video on the left and an image on the right in the same line in html  without using CSS

Comment: Could you expand  a bit on what you mean by 'align' - the bottom of the image and the bottom of the video at the same level, or the tops aligned or....?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use CSS, you could try Bootstrap 4. They have nice flex behavior:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div> # elements on the left side
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div> # elements on the right side
</div>
```

Comment: Technically this uses CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML tables:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" autoplay/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table with one row and two cells. You can simply use 'width' and 'height' attributes to modify its size in your page.

```html
<table width="100%" bgcolor="red" height="200px">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green">
        Your video goes here.
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="blue">
        The image goes here.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```